# Why this state does not update until another does or after fast refresh? - React / NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

**EDIT**: Next version is 13.3.0

I have a state called `localArray` which I want to update only to specific index, so I came with the idea to create a temporal variable to modify that array and update the state with the temporal value, the problem is, this state does not gets updated until another state does or after fast refresh, I don't know why this happens

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function Test() 
{
    const [someState, setSomeState] = useState("");
    const [localArray, setLocalArray] = useState(["","","",""])

    const handleArrayChanges = ( { target: { name, value } } ) => {
        let newArray = localArray;
        newArray[Number(name)] = value;
        setLocalArray(newArray);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Array state</h4>
            <textarea name='0' onChange={handleArrayChanges}/>
            <p> {localArray[0]}</p>

            <h4>Some other state</h4>
            <button onClick={() => {setSomeState("a")}}>Update some other state</button>
        </div>
      )
}

export default Test
```

As you can see, after the array states updates, the first element should show on the paragraph, but never does until the explained ciscumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is built on the assumption that state is immutable. You are mutating the existing array, not creating a new one, so after you set the state react compares the before and after states, sees that they are the same array, and thus believes that nothing has changed. Thus it does not rerender.

Instead, create a copy of the array and modify that:

```
const handleArrayChanges = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
  let newArray = [...localArray]; // <--- creating a shallow copy
  newArray[Number(name)] = value;
  setLocalArray(newArray);
};
```